# UIButton selected image not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

I have a problem with the UIButton, when it's selected. The code is in **Swift 3**:

```
let radioButton = UIButton(type: .system)
radioButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
radioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "buttonUnchecked"), for: .normal)
radioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "buttonChecked"), for: .selected)
radioButton.setTitle("This is some text.", for: .normal)
radioButton.sizeToFit()
```

When it's selected by `radioButton.isSelected = true`, no image is shown.

Comment: Did you check that the image `buttonChecked` exists without typo?

Comment: Have you added radioButton to your view?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a target like this

```
radioButton.addTarget(self, action: "addMethodName", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

and in the method you change the image like this :

```
radioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "buttonUnchecked"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: Yes, this would be possible if I don't use the "selected" state. But I want to use it because of the default colored background of the button label.
Some more ideas? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Custom button type instead of System type. Try this:

```
    let radioButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
```

instead of

```
    let radioButton = UIButton(type: .system)
```